# How can I display the current branch and folder path in terminal?

Tags: macos, git, terminal, git-branch

I've been watching some of the Team Treehouse videos and they have a very nice looking terminal when working with Git.

For example they have (something similar):

```
mike@treehouseMac: [/Work/test - feature-branch-name] $ git add .
mike@treehouseMac: [/Work/test - feature-branch-name] $ git commit -m "Some feature."
mike@treehouseMac: [/Work/test - feature-branch-name] $ git checkout master
mike@treehouseMac: [/Work/test - master] $ git status
```

How can my terminal show me some useful information of what branch I'm on, with colors to distinguish bits of the data I want? Is there some sort of de-facto plugin I haven't found yet?

I'm using Mac OSX 10.8

Answer (score 89, accepted):

It's not about a plugin. It's about prompt tricks in the shell.

For a cool setup in bash, check out the `dotfiles` project of this guy:

https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles

To get a fancy prompt, include the `.bash_prompt` in your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`.

To get the exact same prompt as in your question, change the `export PS1` line at the end of `.bash_prompt` like this:

```
export PS1="\[${BOLD}${MAGENTA}\]\u\[$WHITE\]@\[$ORANGE\]\h\[$WHITE\]: [\[$GREEN\]\w\[$WHITE\]\$([[ -n \$(git branch 2> /dev/null) ]] && echo \" - \")\[$PURPLE\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[$WHITE\]] \$ \[$RESET\]"
```

I ended up using all the `.bash*` files from this repository about a month ago, and it's been really useful for me.

For Git, there are extra goodies in `.gitconfig`.

And since you're a mac user, there are even more goodies in `.osx`.

Comment: After this I am getting: `bash: parse_git_branch: command not found`

Comment: @SharikovVladislav Any update on this? How do we solve the `parse_git_branch: command not found`?

Comment: To fix the `parse_git_branch` error you must define a function as:
`parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ \1/'
}`

Comment: `parse_git_branch` was presumably copied from here: https://gist.github.com/joseluisq/1e96c54fa4e1e5647940

Answer (score 217):

For anyone looking for how to do this in macOS Catalina or above (10.15+ incl. Big Sur 11.0) which has deprecated bash in favour of zsh, here is my .zshrc file:

```
parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -n -e 's/^\* \(.*\)/[\1]/p'
}
COLOR_DEF='%f'
COLOR_USR='%F{243}'
COLOR_DIR='%F{197}'
COLOR_GIT='%F{39}'
# About the prefixed `$`: https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_03.html#:~:text=Words%20in%20the%20form%20%22%24',by%20the%20ANSI%2DC%20standard.
NEWLINE=$'\n'
# Set zsh option for prompt substitution
setopt PROMPT_SUBST
export PROMPT='${COLOR_USR}%n@%M ${COLOR_DIR}%d ${COLOR_GIT}$(parse_git_branch)${COLOR_DEF}${NEWLINE}%% '
```

If you don't like the colours I have used, replace the 243/197/39 values with the colour codes as defined here:
https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting

[Prompt substitutions](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html) used:

- `%n`: username
- `%M`: full machine hostname
- `%d`: current working directory
- `%%`: escape sequence to print a `%`

Comment: Where can I find the .zshrc file? I'm on my home directory or /Users/myusername, but if I run ls -lah I can't see it in the list - also there's no .bashrc or .bash_profile. The only related files I can see are .bash_history and .zsh_history

Comment: @ltdev The file does not necessarily exist by default because it is an optional file. If it does not already exist, then you need to create the file using the command ```touch .zshrc``` (in your home directory)

Comment: I'm in Big Sur and for the first time, color appears, and everything works EXCEPT the git branch still doesn't show. :( At least this got me further along than before! Yay colors!

Comment: So after saying that, I went to add the git branch to the iterm status bar and it was saying invalid git path. After I fixed that, your solution worked. THANK YOU! Here's a fix: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/why-am-i-getting-an-invalid-active-developer-path-when-attempting-to-use-git-a

Comment: Thanks! I had to add a \ before `\$(parse_git_branch)` call to get it to run on every new line, otherwise I would still see the branch outside of a git repo.

Comment: If Line Content doesn't fit available space in Terminal Window, i get some formatting issue in form of leading free space before cursor. What problem is that?

Comment: @Merowinger for some reason none of the solutions on this page worked for me (big sur), but this older one did: https://github.com/olivierverdier/zsh-git-prompt

Comment: This worked out great (on OSx M1). Thank you romiem 

Comment: To display the current folder instead of the full path, change the part in the last line to: `${COLOR_DIR}%.%f ${COLOR_GIT}`

Comment: Thank you, in case you can't find zshrc file in your home check this answer https://superuser.com/a/886135/1653602

Comment: I like to show the last path component instead of the entire path which can take up a lot of space, so my adjustment is `%1d` instead of `%d` :D

Comment: another way is to use  `%2C` it will print current directory name with parent directory name. increase the number to change Level

Answer (score 113):

Simple way

Open `~/.bash_profile` in your favorite editor and add the following content to the bottom.

Git branch in prompt.

```
parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}

export PS1="\u@\h \[\033[32m\]\w - \$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
```

[Add Git Branch To Terminal Prompt (Mac)](http://martinfitzpatrick.name/article/add-git-branch-name-to-terminal-prompt-mac)

Comment: I liked this with a \n before the $ sign at the end to put my prompt on the next line.

Comment: Took 5 mins to fully customize! Here are the color: https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting

Comment: As in latest versions of mac bash_profile is not loaded everytime. So, it is better to setup on the `.zshrc`. Thanks

Answer (score 29):

For Mac Catilina 10.15.5 and later version:

add in your ~/.zshrc file

```sh
function parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -n -e 's/^\* \(.*\)/[\1]/p'
}

setopt PROMPT_SUBST
export PROMPT='%F{grey}%n%f %F{cyan}%~%f %F{green}$(parse_git_branch)%f %F{normal}$%f '
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me! Is there any way of hiding the full path and show only the current folder?

Comment: @bibsbarreto  change PROMPT  from `%~` to  `%.`
so final is : `export PROMPT='%F{grey}%n%f %F{cyan}%.%f %F{green}$(parse_git_branch)%f %F{normal}$%f `

Reference: https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Prompt-Expansion

Comment: Thanks this is the one that only worked for me!!

Comment: This adds a space after the tilde (~). To remove the space, you can use this: parse_git_branch() { git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'}
setopt PROMPT_SUBST
export PROMPT='%F{normal}%n%f %F{cyan}%.%f%F{green}$(parse_git_branch)%f %F{normal}$%f'

Answer (score 25):

To expand on the existing great answers, a very simple way to get a great looking terminal is to use the open source **Dotfiles** project.

https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles

---

[image]

---

Installation is dead simple on OSX and Linux. Run the following command in Terminal.

```
git clone https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles.git && cd dotfiles && source bootstrap.sh
```

This is going to:

1. Git clone the repo.
2. `cd` into the folder.
3. Run the installation bash script.

Comment: any ideas on how to reverse this ??

Comment: find a way to reverse it @ChickenWing24 ?

Comment: @ollaollu i did reverse it in a way. it was a long time back though, so can't recall the steps 100%. but what I did was basically delete all the files/folders that was related to that repo.

Comment: okay thanks, followed something similar to this and it worked

Comment: it should be noted that this one-liner can potentially overwrite a lot of files, so be careful

Comment: ALERT:  Don’t blindly use my settings unless you know what that entails. Use at your own risk!

Comment: WAY TO REVERSE:  reset terminal to default settings https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4656465?tstart=0

Comment: its working with me, but why after typing any command its informing me " ignoring UNTR extension
ignoring UNTR extension
ignoring UNTR extension"

Comment: This adds TONS of configurations without even taking care of making a backup of the files it writes.

Comment: This is an extreme move that will wreak havoc on all of your settings.

Comment: this is dangerous, consumed a lot of time to reverse

Comment: I found a shortcut to reverse this. Enter the `brew.sh` file and replace all mentions of `install` for `purge` and run again.

Answer (score 23):

My prompt includes:

- Exit status of last command (if not 0)
- Distinctive changes when root
- `rsync`-style `user@host:pathname` for copy-paste goodness
- Git branch, index, modified, untracked and upstream information
- Pretty colours

Example:
 [image: Screenshot of my prompt in action]
To do this, add the following to your `~/.bashrc`:

```bash
#
# Set the prompt #
#

# Select git info displayed, see /usr/share/git/completion/git-prompt.sh for more
export GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1           # '*'=unstaged, '+'=staged
export GIT_PS1_SHOWSTASHSTATE=1           # '$'=stashed
export GIT_PS1_SHOWUNTRACKEDFILES=1       # '%'=untracked
export GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM="verbose"     # 'u='=no difference, 'u+1'=ahead by 1 commit
export GIT_PS1_STATESEPARATOR=''          # No space between branch and index status
export GIT_PS1_DESCRIBE_STYLE="describe"  # detached HEAD style:
#  contains      relative to newer annotated tag (v1.6.3.2~35)
#  branch        relative to newer tag or branch (master~4)
#  describe      relative to older annotated tag (v1.6.3.1-13-gdd42c2f)
#  default       exactly eatching tag

# Check if we support colours
__colour_enabled() {
    local -i colors=$(tput colors 2>/dev/null)
    [[ $? -eq 0 ]] && [[ $colors -gt 2 ]]
}
unset __colourise_prompt && __colour_enabled && __colourise_prompt=1

__set_bash_prompt()
{
    local exit="$?" # Save the exit status of the last command

    # PS1 is made from $PreGitPS1 + <git-status> + $PostGitPS1
    local PreGitPS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}"
    local PostGitPS1=""

    if [[ $__colourise_prompt ]]; then
        export GIT_PS1_SHOWCOLORHINTS=1

        # Wrap the colour codes between \[ and \], so that
        # bash counts the correct number of characters for line wrapping:
        local Red='\[\e[0;31m\]'; local BRed='\[\e[1;31m\]'
        local Gre='\[\e[0;32m\]'; local BGre='\[\e[1;32m\]'
        local Yel='\[\e[0;33m\]'; local BYel='\[\e[1;33m\]'
        local Blu='\[\e[0;34m\]'; local BBlu='\[\e[1;34m\]'
        local Mag='\[\e[0;35m\]'; local BMag='\[\e[1;35m\]'
        local Cya='\[\e[0;36m\]'; local BCya='\[\e[1;36m\]'
        local Whi='\[\e[0;37m\]'; local BWhi='\[\e[1;37m\]'
        local None='\[\e[0m\]' # Return to default colour

        # No username and bright colour if root
        if [[ ${EUID} == 0 ]]; then
            PreGitPS1+="$BRed\h "
        else
            PreGitPS1+="$Red\u@\h$None:"
        fi

        PreGitPS1+="$Blu\w$None"
    else # No colour
        # Sets prompt like: ravi@boxy:~/prj/sample_app
        unset GIT_PS1_SHOWCOLORHINTS
        PreGitPS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w"
    fi

    # Now build the part after git's status

    # Highlight non-standard exit codes
    if [[ $exit != 0 ]]; then
        PostGitPS1="$Red[$exit]"
    fi

    # Change colour of prompt if root
    if [[ ${EUID} == 0 ]]; then
        PostGitPS1+="$BRed"'\$ '"$None"
    else
        PostGitPS1+="$Mag"'\$ '"$None"
    fi

    # Set PS1 from $PreGitPS1 + <git-status> + $PostGitPS1
    __git_ps1 "$PreGitPS1" "$PostGitPS1" '(%s)'

    # echo '$PS1='"$PS1" # debug    
    # defaut Linux Mint 17.2 user prompt:
    # PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;34m\] \w\[\033[00m\] $(__git_ps1 "(%s)") \$ '
}

# This tells bash to reinterpret PS1 after every command, which we
# need because __git_ps1 will return different text and colors
PROMPT_COMMAND=__set_bash_prompt
```

Comment: This is amazingly clean code for an info-packed prompt. I spent many hours working on my prompt and climbing out of pitfalls, to arrive at basically what you have here. I highly recommend to start with this code if working on a custom, colorized, git status on the prompt.

Comment: Props to you Tom, this is by far the most clean and easy to modify solution I came across. @wisbucky was absolutely right

Comment: I was here for customizing output from __git_ps1 and learned something new: "Wrap the colour codes between \[ and \], so that bash counts the correct number of characters for line wrapping". I was wondering why so many default colorized ps1s had the "extraneous" brackets

Answer (score 19):

In 2019, I think `git branch --show-current` is a better command than the accepted answer.

```
$ git branch --show-current
master
```

(Added in git 2.22 release in June 2019)

It runs much faster as it doesn't need to iterate through all branches. Similarly `git branch` should be avoided too in the command prompt as it slows down your prompt if you have many local branches.

Put it in a function to use anywhere on command prompt:

```
  # This function returns '' in all below cases:
  #   - git not installed or command not found
  #   - not in a git repo
  #   - in a git repo but not on a branch (HEAD detached)
  get_git_current_branch() {
    git branch --show-current 2> /dev/null
  }
```

More context:

```
$ git version
git version 2.23.0
```

Comment: Excellent answer in 2019. The accepted and Most Upvoted answer are showing their age.

Comment: minimal and perfect answer :D

Answer (score 15):

Just Install the `oh-my-zsh` plugins as described in [this link](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh).

[image]

It works best on macOS and Linux.

**Basic Installation**

Oh My Zsh is installed by running one of the following commands in your terminal. You can install this via the command-line with either `curl` or `wget`.

**via curl**

```
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
```

**via wget**

```
sh -c "$(wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh -O -)"
```

Answer (score 7):

for anyone still looking for this , i just installed ohmyz
https://ohmyz.sh/#install and the branches it's showing
[image]

Comment: This is what I need! Thanks

Answer (score 7):

In the new Catalina OS for Mac

i) **zsh** way. Add below lines in `.zshrc`

```
parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ \1/'
}
COLOR_DEF='%f'
COLOR_DIR='%F{197}'
COLOR_GIT='%F{33}'
setopt PROMPT_SUBST
export PROMPT='${COLOR_DIR}%1d${COLOR_DEF}${COLOR_GIT}$(parse_git_branch)${COLOR_DEF} $ '
```

ii) Or to use old **bash**, you need to change

```
   System Preference -> Users & Groups -> Right click user user
     -> Advanced Option -> Login shell -> /bin/bash
```

Write .bash_profile as below and restart the system

```
parse_git_branch() {
     git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ \1/'
}
export PS1="\W\[\033[33m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
```

Output: `FolderName BranchName $`

Comment: Please use warp or iTerminal. It will have in default.

Answer (score 4):

For macOS:

**Step 1:**

Create and edit a `.zshrc` file that will be used for terminal configuration.

```
touch ~/.zshrc; open ~/.zshrc
```

**Step 2:**

Add this to your `~/.zshrc` file:

```
function parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -n -e 's/^\* \(.*\)/[\1]/p'
}

setopt PROMPT_SUBST
export PROMPT='%F{grey}%n%f %F{cyan}%~%f %F{green}$(parse_git_branch)%f %F{normal}$%f '
```

Answer (score 3):

The git package installed on your system includes bash files to aid you in creating an informative prompt. To create colors, you will need to insert terminal escape sequences into your prompt. And, the final ingredient is to update your prompt after each command gets executed by using the built-in variable PROMPT_COMMAND.

Edit your ~/.bashrc to include the following, and you should get the prompt in your question, modulo some color differences.

```
#
# Git provides a bash file to create an informative prompt. This is its standard
# location on Linux. On Mac, you should be able to find it under your Git
# installation. If you are unable to find the file, I have a copy of it on my GitHub.
#
# https://github.com/chadversary/home/blob/42cf697ba69d4d474ca74297cdf94186430f1384/.config/kiwi-profile/40-git-prompt.sh
#
source /usr/share/git/completion/git-prompt.sh

#
# Next, we need to define some terminal escape sequences for colors. For a fuller
# list of colors, and an example how to use them, see my bash color file on my GitHub
# and my coniguration for colored man pages.
#
# https://github.com/chadversary/home/blob/42cf697ba69d4d474ca74297cdf94186430f1384/.config/kiwi-profile/10-colors.sh
# https://github.com/chadversary/home/blob/42cf697ba69d4d474ca74297cdf94186430f1384/.config/kiwi-profile/40-less.sh
#
color_start='\e['
color_end='m'
color_reset='\e[0m'
color_bg_blue='44'

#
# To get a fancy git prompt, it's not sufficient to set PS1. Instead, we set PROMPT_COMMAND,
# a built in Bash variable that gets evaluated before each render of the prompt.
#
export PROMPT_COMMAND="PS1=\"\${color_start}\${color_bg_blue}\${color_end}\u@\h [\w\$(__git_ps1 \" - %s\")]\${color_reset}\n\$ \""

#
# If you find that the working directory that appears in the prompt is ofter too long,
# then trim it.
#
export PROMPT_DIRTRIM=3
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many PS1 generators but [ezprompt](http://ezprompt.net/) has the git status (2nd tab 'Status Elements' ) also.

Answer (score 2):

Based on 6LYTH3's answer I've decided to post my own due to some improvements that may come in handy:

**Simple solution**

Open `~/.bash_profile` and add the following content

```
# \[\e[0m\] resets the color to default color
reset_color='\[\e[0m\]'
#  \[\033[33m\] sets the color to yellow
path_color='\[\033[33m\]'
# \e[0;32m\ sets the color to green
git_clean_color='\[\e[0;32m\]'
# \e[0;31m\ sets the color to red
git_dirty_color='\[\e[0;31m\]'

# determines if the git branch you are on is clean or dirty
git_prompt ()
{
  # Is this a git directory?
  if ! git rev-parse --git-dir > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    return 0
  fi
  # Grab working branch name
  git_branch=$(git branch 2>/dev/null| sed -n '/^\*/s/^\* //p')
  # Clean or dirty branch
  if git diff --quiet 2>/dev/null >&2; then
    git_color="${git_clean_color}"
  else
    git_color="${git_dirty_color}"
  fi
  echo " [$git_color$git_branch${reset_color}]"
}

export PS1="${path_color}\w\[\e[0m\]$(git_prompt)\n"
```

This should:

```
1) Prompt the path you're in, in color: path_color.
2) Tell you which branch are you.
3) Color the name of the branch based on the status of the branch with git_clean_color 
for a clean work directory and git_dirty_color for a dirty one.
4) The brackets should stay in the default color you established in your computer.
5) Puts the prompt in the next line for readability.
```

You can customize the colors with this [list](https://github.com/ryanoasis/public-bash-scripts/blob/master/unix-color-codes.sh)

**Sophisticated Solution**

Another option is to use Git Bash Prompt, install with [this](https://github.com/magicmonty/bash-git-prompt#installation). I used the option via Homebrew on Mac OS X.

`git_prompt_list_themes` to see the themes but I didn't like any of them.

`git_prompt_color_samples` to see available colors.

`git_prompt_make_custom_theme [<Name of base theme>]` to create a new custom theme, this should create a .git-prompt-colors.sh file.

`subl ~/.git-prompt-colors.sh` to open git-prompt-colors.sh and customize:

The .git-prompt-colors.sh file should look like this with my customization

```
    override_git_prompt_colors() {
      GIT_PROMPT_THEME_NAME="Custom"

      # Clean or dirty branch
      if git diff --quiet 2>/dev/null >&2; then
        GIT_PROMPT_BRANCH="${Green}"
      else
        GIT_PROMPT_BRANCH="${Red}"
      fi
    }

    reload_git_prompt_colors "Custom"
```

Hope this helps, have a great day!

Comment: thanks for the script, this works well in my ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: Glad to be of help! I use a Mac son that means it works for both Mac and some Ubuntus

Answer (score 1):

Keep it fast, keep it simple

put this in your `~/.bashrc` file.

```
git_stuff() {
  git_branch=$(git branch --show-current 2> /dev/null)
  if [[ $git_branch == "" ]];then
    echo -e ""
  elif [[ $git_branch == *"Nocommit"* ]];then
    echo -e "No commits"
  else
    echo -e "$git_branch"
  fi
}
prompt() {
  PS1="\e[2m$(date +%H:%M:%S.%3N) \e[4m$(git_stuff)\033[0m\n\w$ "
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt
```

Then `source ~/.bashrc`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Catalina and above, you can open your .zshrc file by running `nano ~/.zshrc`, and posting the following at the top of the document:

```
# Show git branch in terminal
function parse_git_branch() {
 git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -n -e 's/^\* \(.*\)/[\1]/p'
}

COLOR_DEF=$'\e[0m'
COLOR_USR=$'\e[38;5;243m'
COLOR_DIR=$'\e[38;5;220m’
COLOR_GIT=$'\e[38;5;39m'
setopt PROMPT_SUBST
export PROMPT='${COLOR_USR}%n ${COLOR_DIR}%~
${COLOR_GIT}$(parse_git_branch)${COLOR_DEF} $ '
```

Exit and save. Restart your terminal, or run `exec zsh` and that should be it.

**OR**

You can check out this theme and see if you like it. It is really easy to install and looks good in my opinion:

https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k#configuration

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

From Mac OS Catalina
.bash_profile is replaced with .zprofile

Step 1:
Create a .zprofile

```
touch .zprofile
```

Step 2:

```
nano .zprofile
```

type below line in this

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

and save(ctrl+o return ctrl+x)

Step 3:
Restart your terminal

**To Add Git Branch Name**
Now you can add below lines in .bash_profile

```
    parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}

export PS1="\u@\h \[\033[32m\]\w - \$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
```

Restart your terminal this will work.

**Note:**
Even you can rename .bash_profile to .zprofile that also works.

Comment: the next message appear after that changes and does not works -> `zsh compinit: insecure directories, run compaudit for list.
Ignore insecure directories and continue [y] or abort compinit [n]? `

Comment: Where can I find the .zprofile file? I'm on my home directory or /Users/myusername, but if I run ls -lah I can't see it in the list - also there's no .bashrc or .bash_profile or .zshrc. The only related files I can see are .bash_history and .zsh_history

Answer (score 0):

Did some searching & then adjusted it a bit & settled with this.

```
vi ~/.zshrc
```

And within zshrc file ->

```
function git_branch_name()
{
  branch=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null | awk 'BEGIN{FS="/"} {print $NF}')
  if [[ $branch == "" ]];
  then
    :
  else
    echo '- ('$branch')'
  fi
}
setopt prompt_subst
prompt='%n %1/ $(git_branch_name) $ '
```