# Customize colors for __git_ps1 with GIT_PS1_SHOWCOLORHINTS

Tags: git, shell, command-prompt

### What I have tried

I have updated my prompt to include the branch name using `__git_ps1`. In addition, I set `GIT_PS1_SHOWCOLORHINTS`.

### The problem

The prompt appears correctly. However, the branch color is always green. I expected a dirty branch to be red.

The docs state:

> The colors are based on the colored output of "git status -sb"

I found and reviewed [How to colorize git-status output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795790/how-to-colorize-git-status-output) But I'm not sure what options I'd need to change...

### The question

Is it possible to change the branch color to be green for a *clean* branch and red for a *dirty* branch? If so, how?

Answer (score 17):

The colours shown by `__git_ps1` for dirty branches don't affect the branch name; they affect the "dirty state indicator". In addition to enabling colours, if you enable this indicator you will see a red asterisk for a dirty branch:

```
old-prompt $ bash --noprofile --norc
bash-4.2$ source /etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt
bash-4.2$ export GIT_PS1_SHOWCOLORHINTS=1
bash-4.2$ export GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1
bash-4.2$ export PROMPT_COMMAND='__git_ps1 "\u@\h:\w" "\\\$ "'
chris@machine:~/path/to/dir (master *)$
```

There is no way to change the colour of the branch name based on dirty status without modifying the `git-prompt.sh` code, or providing your own function.

Note that this works with `export PROMPT_COMMAND` but not `export PS1`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but they do not seem to affect the *dirty state indicator* either. Where did you determine that?

Comment: By testing, though it only seems to work when I set `PROMPT_COMMAND` instead of `PS1`, which I didn't include before. I have updated my example.

Comment: + My mistake. I see now that it is indeed marking the *dirty state indicator*. Not really the answer I was looking for. But I can modify the code.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to achieve a decent solution by:
1. Cloning the latest git source, to obtain and install a recent `git-prompt.sh` (Your distro may already have an up-to-date script)
2. Removing the check that is stopping the script from inserting color codes in the output string.
3. Altering my .bashrc to include a call to `__git_ps1` with some formatting options to alter my terminal prompt text.

Commit and documentation, including specific files and edits I made: https://github.com/karlapsite/git/commit/b34d9e8b690ec0b304eb794011938ab49be30204#diff-a43cc261eac6fbcc3578c94c2aa24713R449

Now, my console has all of the information I wanted: I can open a terminal, and cd into any git repo:
`$ cd ~/Github/git
user@hostname:~/Github/git:(master)$ # 'master' is green`

And the when I checkout a hash, and move into a detached head state:
`$ git checkout bca18110
user@hostname:~/Github/git:(bca1811...)$ # the commit hash is red`

I needed to follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13997892/4717806 to have bash properly re-interpret the color codes after each command, but my terminal is intact, linewrapping still works, and my prompt is colored the way I wanted!

Comment: If you call `__git_ps1` with the correct arguments, you don't need to hack `contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh`. See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333531/how-can-i-display-the-current-branch-and-folder-path-in-terminal/38758377#38758377

Comment: Absolutely, setting `PROMPT_COMMAND='__git_ps1 [PRE] [POST]'` is a much cleaner solution!

Answer (score 0):

The way I have solved this issue was to write a short formatting function, which:

1. works with PS1
2. colorizes even the branch
3. customizes messages/notes to include

```bash
  # Craft some nice coloured git status
  __fancy_git_status() {
    local STATUS COLOR NOTE GIT_PS
    STATUS=$(git status -sb --ignore-submodules 2>/dev/null)
    GIT_PS=$(if test $? -eq 0; then
      if grep -q '^A' <<<"$STATUS"; then
        COLOR=${COLOR_INTENSE_GREEN}
        NOTE=" ${COLOR_YELLOW}staged 4 commit$COLOR"
      elif grep -q '^ M' <<<"$STATUS"; then
        COLOR="${COLOR_GREEN}"
        NOTE=" ${COLOR_ORANGE}with changes$COLOR"
      else
        COLOR="${COLOR_INTENSE_GREEN}"
      fi
      __git_ps1 "${GIT_PS1_PREFIX}$COLOR⎇  %s${NOTE:-}"
    fi)
    test -n "$GIT_PS" && echo "$GIT_PS" || echo -e "${GIT_PS1_PREFIX}${COLOR_GRAY}not found"
  }

  PS1="..."  # Your preferred PS1 preceding the git information

  PS1+="\n"
  PS1+="${COLOR_DARK_GREEN}\$(__fancy_git_status)\n${COLOR_RESET}"

  PS1+="\\$ "
```

Here's how it looks in my terminal with clean branch:

[image: showcase of defined PS1 function call - clean state]

Dirty, but not staged:

[image: showcase of defined PS1 function call - dirty state]

Staged for commit:

[image: showcase of defined PS1 function call - staged state]